# regex for telephone number

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Just a simple regex required to validate telephone numbers.

Must contain only digits, and the other allowable characters are spaces and dashes.

Comment: There are many regular expression libraries on the web, did you try to google? Otherwise you could easily try to construct a regexp yourself. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3966

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
if(preg_match('/^[\d -]+$/',$telNumber)) {
  // valid tel number.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
\+?[\d -\(\)]*
```